# Access camera from browser without using flash/silverlight

Tags: asp.net, html, ipad

I want to access camera from browser. I got a good solution at [XARG](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/), but this is using flash and thus doesn't suits my requirement(won't work in IPad). Now I want to know, if there is any other way to access camera without using flash/silverlight.

I am also thinking getusermedia(HTML5) but it has very poor browser support.

Another option could be phonegap, but I am not sure about how to use it also I didn't got any link for a live sample using phone gap.

I am open to all options provided that works on IPad's browser. I am using ASP.NET and HTML5. Any pointer's appreciated. Thanks.

Ravi

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: "What’s your favorite ______?" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. Also see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) This may be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm a fan for leading your target. Aim for where you'll be once your project is done. It won't be long before getUserMedia is available in all browsers. Go this direction. Mozilla has it in it's Nightly's already, Opera has implemented it, Chrome pioneered it, and IE sucks. So just about everything is covered. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera support in the *browser* is currently only available in one of two ways:

1. Using Flash player
2. Using HTML standard = getUserMedia()

Each have their benefits, but as you mentioned not all are supported universally across browsers, and I think the iPad fails to support either (Note: BlackBerry 10 supports both Flash and getUserMedia):

http://html5test.com/compare/browser/bb10/ios60/android40.html

If you want to use a standalone framework like PhoneGap, here is a link to the camera API documentation:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera